# Sysfs or read() system call for userspace interrupt notification

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have created a driver that uses `sysfs_notify_dirent()` to wake up a userspace thread asynchronously when a PCIe device interrupts the kernel driver. I see that this is the interface the most GPIO drivers use to pass interrupts up to userspace. After doing some research though I see that UIO uses the `read()` system call to do pretty much the same thing. Is there any advantage (speed or otherwise) to using the `read()` system call instead of the sysfs interface to pass interrupts. I like the sysfs interface because it allows me to create multiple attributes so I can pass different interrupts to userspace separately.

Comment: I guess on `read()` you may return a number of interrupt of even string.

Comment: sysfs allows me to have multiple threads blocking on different file descriptors. Read would only allow one thread to block on the file descriptor then I would have to parse the return code. I am more interested in speed concerns.

Comment: In case of `read()` you have only one thread handling the interrupts, otherwise you have to implement the same code in each thread that wants to wait for an event. Both methods have pros and cons.